# How can I get day_name() after groupby dayofweek?

Tags: python, pandas, dayofweek

I have a `DatetimeIndex` indexed Series s1 like

```
s1

time
2021-08-24 09:24:16+09:00    11933142
2021-08-24 10:00:03+09:00    11785209
2021-08-24 11:00:03+09:00    14462866
2021-08-24 19:00:04+09:00    11419204
2021-08-24 20:00:03+09:00    11757634
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

and want `mean()` for each day of the week. Then I want to get `day_name()` of the index to draw a graph label but I cannot since `DatetimeIndex` now becomes int.

```
g1 = s1.groupby(s1.index.dayofweek).mean()
----> 3 g1.index.day_name()

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'day_name'
```

What is the smartest workaround?

Comment: Groupby the day name?

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. I want to maintain the sorting order of `dayofweek`

Answer (score 1):

Group by `day_name`:

```
>>> s1.groupby(s1.index.day_name()).mean()

Tuesday    12271611.0
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Graph example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar

days = list(calendar.day_name)

s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000, 10000, 365),
               index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31'))

s2.groupby(s2.index.day_name()).mean().reindex(days).plot(kind='bar', rot=45)

plt.show()
```

[image: Graph example]

Comment: Thanks for the sample code!  Is there any way to avoid writing a code

`days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']`

by myself?

Comment: I updated my answer. Use `calendar` module from standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> s1.groupby(s1.index.dayofweek).transform('mean').index.day_name().drop_duplicates()
Index(['Tuesday'], dtype='object')
>>>
```

Comment: It works but has one problem. How can I sort the data starting from Monday?